# Flutter widget test tap - would not hit test on the specified widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

My widget test is failing after the following warning is outputted:

> flutter: Warning: A call to tap() with finder "exactly one widget with text "Tab 2" (ignoring offstage widgets): Text("Tab 2", softWrap: no wrapping except at line break characters, overflow: fade, dependencies: [MediaQuery, DefaultTextStyle])" derived an Offset (Offset(600.0, 23.0)) that would not hit test on the specified widget.
> flutter: Maybe the widget is actually off-screen, or another widget is obscuring it, or the widget cannot receive pointer events.

The tap is never executed so the next part of the test fails. I put some delays in the test and it appears that the test is attempting to tap the correct widget - it is not offscreen, not obscured, and was able to receive pointer events in the past - not sure why it's currently failing.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: TabBar(
            labelColor: Color(0xff8391e4),
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
            ],
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Tab 1 Text'),
              Text('Tab 2 Text'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets('My Test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Warning thrown on this tap - tap never executed
    await tester.tap(find.text('Tab 2'));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Test fails here
    expect(find.text('Tab 2 Text'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, did you find a solution? I tried `ensureVisible` as well. No luck.

Comment: @LeeMordell any news on this? Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Dirk - haven't tested in awhile and no solution unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 15):

Try to set `ensureVisible()` before `tap()`:

```
// Warning thrown on this tap - tap never executed
await tester.ensureVisible(find.text('Tab 2'));
await tester.tap(find.text('Tab 2'));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. [ensureVisible](https://docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/ensureVisible.html) is great when a widget is off-screen and you want to scroll to it; however, in my case the widget is clearly visible on the screen.

Comment: I am currently having the same issue @LeeMordell , but when I run the test on the simulator, it is visible as you mentioned in your comment. Did you manage to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: ensureVisible is not about not being visible in real simulator, is about this specific component being visible on screen on test emulator. So, it simulates a scroll on emulator screen till the related component is visible

Answer (score 3):

Incase, anyone comes across this question in the future.

I had this same problem it was because I had animation still running in the background. The fix is to call `await tester.pumpAndSettle();` which flushes out all pending animations.

I believe a side effect of `ensureVisible()` is something similar which is why it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem, but it may not be a universal solution. The app that this test is for is exclusively a web app so it's designed to run on larger screen sizes. When I'd run the test on chrome it would pass, but would fail when run heedlessly.

To fix, I run the test at a larger screen size and it now passes heedlessly.
So if you run into the `A call to tap() ... that would not hit test on the specified widget` error, adjusting the screen size might fix the issue.

```
  testWidgets('My test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // Here we use physicalSizeTestValue to adjust the test screen size to
      // simulate running on a desktop computer which the app was designed for
      tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = Size(1080, 1920);
      tester.binding.window.devicePixelRatioTestValue = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when running an infinite(!) animation in the background. As the animation was supposed to run infinitely `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` could not be used as this would always times out. Using `await tester.pump()` resulted in the described behavior that taps are no longer recognized/executed.

The fix for me was to call `await tester.pumpFrames(MyApp(), const Duration(seconds: 2))` as recommended in Github issue [#60372](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60372) and [#100130](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100130). A further example is provided in the [AnimationSheetBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/AnimationSheetBuilder-class.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, my custom dialog cover the whole screen, so my button is findable but not tap-able. The solution is tapping on the screen to dismiss the dialog first:

```
  // Verify sign in screen
  await tester.tapAt(Offset(0, 0)); // tap to dismiss toast
  await tester.pump();
  await tester.tap(find.text('VERIFY'));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```