# Flutter test: Tap would not hit the specified widget when testing dropdown

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

I am currently writing tests for a dropdown for my flutter app.

In this app I have a CustomDropdownButton2 to change the language of the app. It contains strings for the different language.

My test for this looks like this so far:

```
  testWidgets('Language change test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build app and trigger frame rebuild
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      EasyLocalization(
        path: 'assets/languages',
        supportedLocales: L10n.all,
        fallbackLocale: const Locale('de', 'DE'),
        child: makeTestableWidget(
          ChangeNotifierProvider<Settings>(
            create: (_) => Settings(),
            child: const SettingsPage(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    // wait for it to finish
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    // Since german is the default language, this should be displayed
    expect(find.text('Einstellungen'), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.tap(find.byKey(const Key('LanguageDropdown')));

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    tester.ensureVisible(find.text('English').last);

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    await tester.tap(find.text('English').last); // this is the part where the warning is thrown
  });
```

It throws the warning **A call to tap() with finder "exactly one widget with text "English" (ignoring all but last) (ignoring offstage widgets): Text("English", inherit: true, size: 14.0, overflow: ellipsis, maxLines: 1, dependencies: [DefaultSelectionStyle, DefaultTextStyle, MediaQuery, _ScrollableScope])" derived an Offset (Offset(91.0, 200.0)) that would not hit test on the specified widget.**

I have tried out the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68366138/flutter-widget-test-tap-would-not-hit-test-on-the-specified-widget) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64490039/flutter-widget-test-does-not-trigger-dropdownbutton-onchanged-when-selecting-ano) question, but no luck so far.